# Show streaming data on a phone

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm new to Android, and am working on an app using bluetooth connection to transfer streaming data from an HC-06 to the smartphone and show it serially on the app screen, then pops the currently oldest data out when the screen is full. Honestly I've no idea of how to make a screen like that. Sorry if my question is not so specific, and all advice are welcome.